# Awk - wrong spaces

Tags: awk

How to get from

```
42001  55836.5692  26.2335   28.3323   -0.5672   -2.0120   -7.6489
42002  55836.5827  26.2097  -14.4487    1.4356   -8.9812   -7.3800
```

this:

```
55836.5692   28.3323    1.000   1   1
55836.5963  -14.4487    1.000   1   1
```

?

I tried

```
awk '{printf "%s%9s\n", $2, $4" 1    1.000    1    1}' SPEFO.RVS > c_1.txt
```

But the spaces in file are wrong. Thank you

**EDIT**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
>> awk '{printf "%5.4f %15.4f %15.4f %15d %15d\n",$2,$4,1.000,1,1 }' SPEFO.RVS 
55836.5692         28.3323          1.0000               1               1
55836.5827        -14.4487          1.0000               1               1
```

You can adjust formatting(e.g. `%5.4f`, to `%5.5f` to display `5` decimals or to `%10.4f` to change position of the first word) according your needs.

Comment: Thank you and is it possible to center the second column according to decimal point? I added the result to my question

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.